# Retrieving row index from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is a small example of what I m trying to do

```
x<-c(11,38,24)

z1<-c(26,42,23,61,11) 
z2<-c(52,38,82,99,74)
z3<-c(19,72,28,24,25)

dat<-data.frame(z1,z2,z3)
```

I want to know which value of the first column of dat is equal to the first element of x, which value of the second column of dat is equal to the second value of x, and so on. Once I have determined these values I want to know what row each element is in.

For example, the first value of x matches the element in the fifth row of the first column of dat, the second value of x matches the element in the second row of the second column of dat, ect.

I want my output to be a vector that looks like this

```
vec<- c(5, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapply`.

```
mapply(function(a, b) which(a == b), dat, x)
# z1 z2 z3 
#  5  2  4
```

And to get your exact desired result, set the `USE.NAMES` argument to `FALSE`

```
mapply(function(a, b) which(a == b), dat, x, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] 5 2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sapply(1:length(x), function(j) which(x[j] == dat[, j]))
```

If you had duplicated elements (like two times the number 11 in the first column) then this would return a list. Otherwise (like in this example) you get a simple vector.